# Pandas - new column based on `max` of grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, assign

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple groups in it, A, B, C. Each group has multiple counts associated with it and I want to create a new column that is normalised to the max value of each group.

i.e.

```
index, group, year, count
0, A, 2015, 1
1, A, 2016, 2
2, A, 2017, 3
3, B, 2012, 10
4, B, 2013, 14
5, B, 2014, 18
6, C, 2014, 55
7, C, 2015, 59
8, C, 2016, 58
```

...becomes

```
index, group, year, count, normalised
0, A, 2015, 1,  0.333
1, A, 2016, 2,  0.667
2, A, 2017, 3,  1.000
3, B, 2012, 10, 0.557
4, B, 2013, 14, 0.778
5, B, 2014, 18, 1.000
6, C, 2014, 55, 0.932
7, C, 2015, 59, 1.000
8, C, 2016, 58, 0.983
```

If I try something like...

`df.assign(normalised=lambda x: x['count']/df[df['group'] == x['group']]['count'].max()`

then `max` will return `59` rather than the largest number within the category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` to calculate the ratio between current value and maximum value in each group:

```
df['normalised'] = df['count'].groupby(df.group).transform(lambda x: x / x.max())

df
   index group  year  count  normalised
0      0     A  2015      1    0.333333
1      1     A  2016      2    0.666667
2      2     A  2017      3    1.000000
3      3     B  2012     10    0.555556
4      4     B  2013     14    0.777778
5      5     B  2014     18    1.000000
6      6     C  2014     55    0.932203
7      7     C  2015     59    1.000000
8      8     C  2016     58    0.983051
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom and @timgeb - these both work. Confused as to why though! It's not clear to me how Pandas knows what the denominator should be for each row. In this example, won't the `groupby` create a `groupby` object with three `max` numbers? (It's slightly more intuitive with the `lambda` function)

Comment: Edit: OK, beginning to understand...! https://datagy.io/pandas-groupby/

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Psidom's answer, but avoiding the the `lambda` and therefore faster:

```
df['normalised'] = df['count']/df.groupby('group')['count'].transform('max')
```

Timings

```
>>> %timeit df['normalised'] = df['count']/df.groupby('group')['count'].transform('max')                                         
1.16 ms ± 79.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>>                                                                                                                              
>>> %timeit df['normalised'] = df['count'].groupby(df.group).transform(lambda x: x / x.max())                                    
1.86 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```